# What kind of checksum algorithm?

Tags: checksum

i trying to comunicate with an bluetooth device and already have the commando codes. the problem is i think theres is a checksum algorithm implemented and i dont know which one. Already tried some algorithms but without success. Here are some commando codes as hex array:

C0 54 07  00 01 00 00 01 10 02  FA 
C0 54 07  00 01 00 00 02 10 02  22 
C0 54 07  00 00 00 00 02 10 02  0C 
C0 54 07  01 00 00 00 02 10 02  AC 
C0 54 07  01 00 00 01 02 10 02  56 
C0 54 07  01 00 00 01 02 10 03  F0 
C0 54 07  01 00 00 01 02 11 03  88

The first 3 bytes are always the same so i dont think hey are included in the calculation. Must be the adress or something similar. The 7 Bytes in the middle: the adjacent byte arrays are always differ in just one byte. I captured the commandos with wireshark while i changed one parameter after another on the device successively. On the device are 7 function. That indicates that each of the 7 bytes should be for one different parameter. The last byte shold be a checksum, i think. because its always a different one. 
I i would appreciate if somebody can help!